# How to make smoother scroll transitions?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code https://jsfiddle.net/ehjfku1q/1/

```js
const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
  refreshInterval: 0
});

let tween = new TimelineMax()
  .fromTo(".section__block--1 .section__title", .25, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1.6,
    fontWeight: 700,
    mixBlendMode: 'screen',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 0)

  .fromTo(".section__block--1 .section__title", .25, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1.6
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1,
    fontWeight: 300,
    mixBlendMode: 'normal',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 1)

  .fromTo(".section__block--1 .section__caption", .2, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '0',
    opacity: 0,
    y: '100%'
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '500px',
    opacity: 1,
    y: '0%',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 0)

  .fromTo(".section__block--1 .section__caption", .25, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '0',
    opacity: 1
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '0px',
    opacity: 0,
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 1)


  .fromTo(".section__block--2 .section__title", .5, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1.6,
    fontWeight: 700,
    mixBlendMode: 'screen',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 1)

  .fromTo(".section__block--2 .section__title", .5, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1.6
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1,
    fontWeight: 400,
    mixBlendMode: 'normal',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 2)

  .fromTo(".section__block--2 .section__caption", .5, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '0',
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '500px',
    opacity: 1,
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 1)

  .fromTo(".section__block--2 .section__caption", .5, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '0',
    fontWeight: 400,
    opacity: 1
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '0px',
    fontWeight: 400,
    opacity: 0,
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 2)


  .fromTo(".section__block--3 .section__title", .75, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1.6,
    fontWeight: 700,
    mixBlendMode: 'screen',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 2)

  .fromTo(".section__block--3 .section__title", .75, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1.6
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    scale: 1,
    fontWeight: 400,
    mixBlendMode: 'normal',
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 3)

  .fromTo(".section__block--3 .section__caption", .75, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '0',
    opacity: 0
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '500px',
    opacity: 1,
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 2)

  .fromTo(".section__block--3 .section__caption", .75, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '0',
    opacity: 1
  }, {
    x: '0%',
    maxHeight: '0px',
    opacity: 0,
    ease: Linear.easeNone
  }, 3)


new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerHook: .01,
    duration: '400%',
    triggerElement: ".section",
  })
  //.addIndicators()
  .setPin(".section")
  .setTween(tween)
  .addTo(controller)
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 32px
}

.section__block+.section__block {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.section__item {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.section__video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.section__title {
  font-size: 8vw;
  position: relative;
  left: 0%;
  z-index: 9;
  color: #999;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  transition: transform .5s ease-in;
}

.section__caption {
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  color: #ccc;
  max-width: 60%;
  margin-inline: auto;
  margin-block: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.section__caption strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}

footer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/animation.gsap.min.js"></script>


<header></header>

<section class="section">
  <div class="section__block section__block--1">
    <div class="section__item">
      <h2 class="section__title">Title 1</h2>
      <video class="section__video" loop muted autoplay>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <p class="section__caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section__block section__block--2">
    <div class="section__item">
      <h2 class="section__title">Title 2</h2>
      <video class="section__video" loop muted autoplay>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <p class="section__caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section__block section__block--3">
    <div class="section__item">
      <h2 class="section__title">Title 3</h2>
      <video class="section__video" loop muted autoplay>
        <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
    </div>
    <p class="section__caption">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
  </div>
</section>

<footer></footer>
```

Now when scrolling the `.section` block, the transitions are sometimes jerky without smoothness for blocks (Title 1, Title 2, Title 3)

Tell me how to make transitions when scrolling between blocks (Title 1, Title 2, Title 3) smoother?

Thank you. I will be glad for any help

Comment: Testing on an iOS device, it’s not so much that the transitions are jerky but they don’t seem to work, in the sense I see a narrow strip of the video sometimes rather than as background to the titles.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using scroll-snap CSS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap

Comment: the transition happens on one screen at full height, so scroll-snap is not appropriate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).